# Edit a shape's positions with Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

How can I alter a shape's lines after it's created? I create a triangle this way:

```
var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(context) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(200, 50);
      context.lineTo(420, 80);
      context.lineTo(420, 180);
      context.lineTo(200, 50);
      context.closePath();
      context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    },
    fill: fillColor,
    stroke: strokeColor,
    strokeWidth: strokeWidth
});
```

I want one of the coordinates to follow my mouse. How can I change the coordinates of the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

You can reset the drawFunc of your shape like this:

```
triangle.setDrawFunc( function(){…your new drawing…});
```

But the better solution might be to expose the lines as a new property on your shape object:

```
var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(context) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(this.lines[0].x,this.lines[0].y);
      for(var i=1;i<this.lines.length;i++){
          context.lineTo(this.lines[i].x,this.lines[i].y);
      }
      context.closePath();
      context.fillStrokeShape(this);
    },
    fill: fillColor,
    stroke: strokeColor,
    strokeWidth: strokeWidth
});
triangle.lines=[];
```

Then you can set the shape’s lines like this:

```
// then set lines
triangle.lines=[];
triangle.lines.push({x:200,y:50});
triangle.lines.push({x:420,y:80});
triangle.lines.push({x:420,y:180});
triangle.lines.push({x:200,y:50});
```

And reset the shape’s lines like this:

```
// and reset the lines
triangle.lines=[];
triangle.lines.push({x:100,y:100});
triangle.lines.push({x:200,y:150});
triangle.lines.push({x:100,y:200});
```

Or to follow a mouseXY:

```
triangle.lines[2] = { x:mouseX, y:mouseY };
```

**[ addition ]**

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8ZQ5A/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(context) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(this.lines[0].x,this.lines[0].y);
          for(var i=1;i<this.lines.length;i++){
              context.lineTo(this.lines[i].x,this.lines[i].y);
          }
          context.closePath();
          context.fillStrokeShape(this);
        },
        fill: "skyblue",
        stroke: "blue",
        strokeWidth: 3
    });
    triangle.lines=[];
    layer.add(triangle);


    // initially set lines
    triangle.lines=[];
    triangle.lines.push({x:20,y:50});
    triangle.lines.push({x:220,y:80});
    triangle.lines.push({x:220,y:180});
    triangle.lines.push({x:100,y:200});

    layer.draw();


    $("#change").click(function(){

        // reset lines
        triangle.lines=[];
        triangle.lines.push({x:20,y:150});
        triangle.lines.push({x:160,y:220});
        triangle.lines.push({x:180,y:180});
        layer.draw();

    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="change">Change</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Although, this.lines[0] is undefined, you don't assign the property until after the shape is created. How should I solve that?

Comment: The drawFunc is not executed until layer.draw.  So you'll be fine as long as you assign triangle.lines before layer.draw.  I've included sample code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8ZQ5A/  BTW, I had a typo in my original code: in the loop, it should be lineTo not moveTo.

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you for taking your time to help me with this.